# Offline posting on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, offline

User A is currently logged in to my Facebook App and performs an action that I would like to notify user B (which is currently offline).

I tried using the graph API but:

- A is not a friend of B so I cant post using A's session.
- I can post using B's session - but this would be confusing for B that will see a post from himself about A's activity.
- I tried also the deprecated rest API but when specifing a uid which isnt the session user i get an error message.

Is there a way I can notify user B on the action performed by A?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you send a message to user B from user A?

Comment: I don't think there's a programmatic API for sending a message.

Comment: looks like you're right..I don't think what you have in mind is possible :(

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could do that (publish post on wall), if you have a [offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). But this permission could scare some people.

Try remember the access token, and use it to publish while user is already logged out.

Comment: Could do what exactly and how? could you please elaborate. Why do you think offline permission will enable this?

Comment: I mention this option in my question "I can post using B's session" - the problem is that the posting user would be B; B's image and name would be used. So imagine user A added a comment on B's question. B will see a post from himself that A added a comment ...

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding, maybe this(notifications.sendEmail - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/) will help you. If not I think there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: thanks, this sounds like a good workaround. Ill test it and if it works ill update you so that you can update the answer and ill accept it.